# Need help on deleting row(s) from a SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce, delete-row

Another question today. This time, I'm having trouble deleting a row from a SQL Server CE database.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Create a connection to the file datafile.sdf in the program folder
        string dbfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\userDtbs.sdf";
        SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile);

        // Read all rows from the table test_table into a dataset (note, the adapter automatically opens the connection)
        SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM history", connection);
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(data);

        //Delete from the database
        using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM accounts WHERE Id = 0", connection))
        {
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        // Save data back to the databasefile
        var cmd = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(adapter);
        adapter.Update(data);

        // Close 
        connection.Close();
}
```

My program's giving me an error telling me that `connection` is in a closed state, and I can't figure out why it would close before the `DELETE` command is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Note that: executing command with `Command.ExecuteXXX()` requires the connection to be open first. Filling data into `DataSet` using `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` doesn't require that because it handles that internally. Executing the `SQL query` this way is direct and don't require any `Update` method call on `adapter` (as you add in your code after deleting). `Update` is just for saving changes made on your `DataSet`.

```
    //Delete from the database
    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE FROM accounts WHERE Id = 0", connection))
    {
        if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```